# Javascript disable button

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I need to disable couple of HTML Buttons on the page based on a boolean variable coming from the server.

I can access the variable on the JSP page. Do I need an event listener for this task? Any similar example would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact syntax but you could do something like this..

```
<input type="button" <%= disableFlag ? "disabled=\"disabled" : "" %> />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need JS, just add the [`disabled`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp) property to your button.

```
<button type="button" disabled="disabled">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Hi Mike, already got 2 down votes :( Thanks for the reply. so a simple <c:if test=""> would do in this case, right?

Comment: @DojoBlunder, I can't help you with JSP syntax.  Sorry.